# trying to give some css styles and better positioning to the code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the following code and it works well but with few exceptions:

1. Unable to move to the position based upon the screen resolution and div height and width, basically if the contents are low, it is hising it self after showing a small portion and cutting off the remaining.
2. Trying to make the [X] to stay at the top right corner always even if the size of the div box is small or big
3. better css styling for the contents:

Here is my code:

```js
$('a.structureTypes').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-value');
    var boxID = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $("#Structure" + boxID).fadeIn('slow');
});
$('.cancelStruct').click(function() {
    var boxID = $(this).attr('data-cancel');
    $('#Structure' + boxID).hide();
});
```

```css
#box1 {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #000;
    display: none;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    height: 100px;
    opacity: 0.6;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Structure2" align="center" style="display: none; background: red;">
    <table align="center" style="
        background: white;
        ">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Test Page 1<br/>test page2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button type="button" data-cancel="2" class="cancelStruct">X</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

http://prntscr.com/cndank

Comment: can you provide `jsfiddle` ?

Comment: You might want to include the **a.structureTypes** element otherwise your code does not "unhide" your result.  It is also unclear what your desired result actually is.  Can you post an image (even hand drawn) of what you hope the end result might be?

Comment: here is the screenshot attached

Comment: any idea guys how can i fix it

Comment: here is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/j55dpv3y/3/